# SignalR-Objc Invoke Completion Handler Not Called

Tags: objective-c, signalr, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to use the completion handler on invoke to perform certain actions once the hub has return a result. Im using the following line currently:

```
myHub invoke:@"stpm" withArgs:messageParam completionHandler:^(SRHubResult *hubResult) {
NSLog(@"Complete");
}
```

But the block is never called. The invoke still works fine but the block never gets used. Any suggestions as to why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue. In SRHubProxy.m when the method send is called from SRHubProxy.m in invoke, the line:

```
[_connection send:hubData];
```

is wrong. The block never gets passed whether you have declared one or not. I changed it to:

```
[_connection send:hubData completionHandler:block];
```

which now passes the block correctly and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I can only spot 1.5 issues with your snippet, completionHandler returns either NSDictionary, NSArray, NSNumber, or NSString. Also, is messageParam array?

Comment: oh forgot about this question. You actually saw the answer to this on github. I made the issue there and pointed out how the block is being passed as nil.

Comment: ahh thought it look sorta familiar.